# Query about PHP with undefined offset error on random

Tags: php

I am new to coding and I'm trying to learn PHP by making a Tic Tac Toe game.

The PHP below is an attempt to make the server place an "O" in random in an empty slot each submit.

```
$empties = array();
$gameBoard = array();
$rand = 1;
for ($i = 0; $i < 9; $i++) {
    $gameBoard[$i] = "";
}

if (isset($_POST['gameBoard'])) {

    $gameBoard = $_POST['gameBoard'];

    for ($i = 0; $i < 9; $i++) {
        if ($gameBoard[$rand] !== 'X' and $gameBoard[$rand] !== 'O') {
            $gameBoard[$rand] = 'O';
            break;
        }
        $rand = rand(1, 9);
    }
```

However it does ,on random,work for a while and then throws undefined offset error or does not place an "O" at all.

This is the full code:
http://phpfiddle.org/main/code/wza8-3niu

Your help is most appreciated.

Comment: You do realize that you overwrite `$gameBoard` with _what ever_ the client posts in your conditional block? Why do you expect `$gameBoard[...]` to always exist then?

Comment: This requires debugging on your end. Accessing an array index that is not set gives you that warning. Take a look when that happens, to do that, check if the index exists before you access it. The solution is in the end to only use existing indexes.

Comment: May I ask how this question is a duplicate?
Also...my array is set to ="" on all its indexes by the for loop as far as I can understand.

P.s.
I'm new to coding and obviously make rudimentary mistakes.

Answer (score 0):

NVM I fixed it thanks anyway :)

```
  for ($i = 0; $i < 9; $i++) {
        $rand = rand(1, 9);
        if ($gameBoard[$rand] !== 'X' and $gameBoard[$rand] !== 'O') {
            $gameBoard[$rand] = 'O';
            break;
        }
    }
```

Comment: $rand = rand(0, 8);****

forgot arrays start at 0 not 1...